# How can I build a composite structure(minerals) in the materials studio?

Tags: simulation, moleculer, lammps, materials

I wanna make a composite structure including two oxide minerals, in common surface in materials studio software.

I can't build a comosite structure of two or multi minerals with a common surface. The modeled surface should be a composition of TiO2 and SiO2.